# How to hide login form after reaching the total of failed login attempts?

Tags: laravel, authentication, laravel-5, laravel-5.8, throttling

I want to hide the login form and display an error message instead, but I can't.

I tried to put the code below that rewrites the action on the controller that shows the form, but the method that checks for too many login attempts doesn't seem to work and never returns true.

```
public function showLoginForm(Request $request)
{
    if (method_exists($this, 'hasTooManyLoginAttempts') &&
        $this->hasTooManyLoginAttempts($request) ) {
            $seconds = $this->limiter()->availableIn($this->throttleKey($request));
            return view('auth.block', array(
                'seconds' => $seconds
            ));
    }

    return view('auth.login');
}
```

I managed the authentication process with php artisan make: auth login controller is the default generated by Laravel, the only change is in the action that displays the form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at Laravel's code, it checks for `hasTooManyLoginAttempts` based on `throttleKey` and `maxAttempts`.

The `throttleKey` is dependent on the user's email and IP address. So the output of the following code is something like: `info@example.com|127.0.0.1` and that is your `throttleKey`.

```
protected function throttleKey(Request $request)
{
    return Str::lower($request->input($this->username())).'|'.$request->ip();
}
```

Now Laravel gets the user's email (username) from `$request->input($this->username())` when you send a `POST` request, which you don't have access to in the `showLoginForm` method because it's called on the `GET` request.

Anyway, if you want to block the login form you'll need to come up with your own unique `throttleKey` and then override the method. Say you want your `throttleKey` to be based only on the IP address - which is not recommended. Here's how you do it:

```
// In LoginController.php 

protected function throttleKey(Request $request)
{
    return $request->ip();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The function `hasTooManyLoginAttempts()` needs, in the `$request`, the `username` (usually the email) as a key to know if the `user` has reached his max login attempts.

If, in the $request, there is not the `username` with a value the function is unable to verify the `user` *login attempts*.

So you cannot really know who is the user that wants to `get` your login form, you know who is only *after* he submitted the form.

IMHO the only way could be to add a `username` parameter to the GET request but you shoud provide it with some workarounds: cookies, session etc.